# Permission restriction to do go get command on default user jenkins:jenkins on jenkins pod

Tags: docker, go, jenkins, permissions, sudo

I have a docker container that uses a debian image, and inside it, I need to run some **Go get commands **, using the user jenkins:jenkins, because it is the user jenkins use when running a build, but this user by itself don't have permission to do that(mkdir and creating files).

Tried to install sudo on image and run "sudo go get" on jenkins, but it doesn't work because of the env variables.

The dockerfile image I'm using is this one:

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN apt-get install sudo

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common curl git jq wget unzip

RUN curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.15.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz| tar -v -C /usr/local -xz
ENV PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Before trying to execute the sudo operations, I enter `echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers` just to make sure that the password won't be needed

Since I'm going to use this image in jenkins later on, I need a solution that I could implement in a "non interactive" way, preferably configuring it directly in the dockerfile.

Thanks!!

Comment: because `go` is not in the path when executing `sudo`. Note that you should never need to execute `go` with `sudo` in the first place.

Comment: The need came because jenkins. The project its going to the build there, and it uses the user jenkins:jenkins, and we have limitations to edit jenkins itself, so since it's going to be used only to build the project, the "sudo go" option seems the best one

Comment: If you must use `sudo`, have you tried `-E`? This is not really related to Go or programming in general, since it's just a problem using `sudo`.

Comment: You should never need to use `sudo` in Docker either.  If you're running a container, `docker run -u root` will do things as root, even if the Dockerfile requests something different; or you can `USER root` inside a Dockerfile to switch back.

Comment: @JimB Tried -E, same result. DavidMaze: This image it's going to be used in jenkins, using kubernetes, and in that container, jenkins it's going to run some commands, using the user jenkins:jenkins, that user by itself it's not going to have the permission on the gopath folder to do anything, that's why I'm trying to make a image that allows me to run a "sudo go" command. Maybe it's not the best way, I know, but we've tried many others before that...

Comment: @DavidMaze Turned out that I was far far away from doing it the "right way", but thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution:**

Just like the comments said, the `sudo go` was not the solution, the solution was to provide the user jenkins:jenkins the permission to do so.

In dockerfile, I've created the user jenkins:jenkins, installed sudo package, and turned the user jenkins into sudo. Pointed the changes with "<-----":

```
    FROM debian:latest
    
    RUN apt-get update
    RUN apt-get upgrade -y
    RUN apt-get install -y gnupg2
    
    RUN apt-get install sudo                          <-----
    RUN addgroup --gid 6002 jenkins                   <-----
    RUN useradd -u 6002 -g jenkins -s /bin/sh jenkins <-----
    RUN usermod -aG sudo jenkins                      <-----    

    RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates software-properties-common curl git jq wget unzip
    
    RUN curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.15.6.linux-amd64.tar.gz| tar -v -C /usr/local -xz
    
    RUN export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
...
```

Doing that, in jenkins I was able to run in the Gopath, with the user that jenkins use(jenkins:jenkins), the command: sh "sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins ./*"

So the **sudo go get** wasn't needed .